# I have unorganized data converted to Tables on Microsoft Access, how should I approach moving the information in an effort to organize this database?

Tags: database, ms-access

[image: Updated table]

I have this information in Access that needs to be moved to two columns (one category, following the value)
What is the most efficient way to do this? Ideally, this is how the information should be organized (output)
[image]

How can I merge Field 1 with Field 3 and Field 5 into one column? And then merge Field 2, Field 4, and Field 6 respectfully along side their value?

This is an update on the original question as I eliminated/imported updated data to get rid of all of the fluff and left only relevant information

Comment: I presume this data is all related to something, such as an account. That data is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNION query might get you close. Consider:

```
SELECT Field1 AS F1, Field2 AS F2 FROM StrippedData WHERE NOT Field1 IS NULL AND NOT FIELD2 IS NULL
UNION ALL SELECT Field3, Field4 FROM StrippedData WHERE NOT Field3 IS NULL AND NOT FIELD4 IS NULL
UNION ALL SELECT Field5, Field6 FROM StrippedData WHERE NOT Field5 IS NULL AND NOT FIELD6 IS NULL;
```

Otherwise, build a VBA procedure manipulating recordset.

Comment: Thank you, June!!

Comment: If answer resolved issue, please mark accepted.

Comment: Hey June, once I have 15 reputation I will be going back to the questions I have asked and giving a plus. Currently, due to being new, I am not allowed to upvote yet. Thank you for the help/guide however.

Comment: You can mark answers as accepted. Upvote would be a bonus.

Comment: Looked up how to mark an answer as accepted, and the green checkmark next to the question does not appear for me yet. Stack Overflow does this so that before I mark answers as accepted, I am trusted beforehand. I will get there, and when I do, I'll accept it. Btw, I edited the question as I redid the data imported before I could get to your answer. If you can, any help would be appreciated however I understand if you choose not to. Looking into Unions and how I can incorporate it into this updated question as we speak

Comment: Ohhhh got it, I was looking below the arrows of my question and not your answer. Apologies as I am a newb

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: So did marking answer accepted get you points? Any more you can mark?

Comment: Good point June!!

Comment: Cheers to you! Thank you.